# python convert list to hex data

Tags: python

My data like this:

```
a = ['aa', '55', '00', '01', '00', '0a']
```

And I want to convert it to:

```
a = '\xaa\x55\x00\x01\x00\x0a'
```

How should I do

Thanks

---

code:

```
a = ['AA', '55', '00', '01', '00', '0A', '0F', 'A1', '13', '88', '00', '04', '32', '33', '30', '31', '30', '34', '00', '01']

d = []
for item in a:
    tmp = chr(int(item, 16))
    d.append(tmp)
    print(type(tmp))

print(repr(''.join(d)))
```

output:

```
ªU\x00\x01\x00\n\x0f¡\x13\x88\x00\x04230104\x00\x01
```

And the result as the same as

```
\xAA\x55\x00\x01\x00\x0A\x0F\xA1\x13\x88\x00\x04\x32\x33\x30\x31\x30\x34\x00\x01
```

I used *print* and *repr* to print it, Is there some way that can print it without auto convert. Thx

Comment: This seems like a homework and it is really easy. You have at least to show what you tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't write any code, so I won't either.

You'll need [`int`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#int) with a `base` argument, you'll need [`chr`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#chr) to convert a number to a char and you'll probably need a list comprehension and [`join`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.join).

Comment: Thx, I sloved it